# can't connect to ssh server with tor address, that is running on docker container

Tags: docker, ssh, tor

I am running ssh server with tor address, that is running on docker container.
This is my dockerfile.

```
FROM kalilinux/kali-rolling

RUN apt clean

RUN apt update && apt install -y openssh-server tor

RUN mkdir /var/run/sshd
RUN echo 'root:root' | chpasswd
RUN sed -i 's/#PermitRootLogin prohibit-password/PermitRootLogin yes/' /etc/ssh/sshd_config
RUN echo "ListenAddress 127.0.0.1" >> /etc/ssh/sshd_config

# Configure Tor hidden service for SSH
RUN echo "HiddenServiceDir /var/lib/tor/ssh_hidden_service/" >> /etc/tor/torrc
RUN echo "HiddenServicePort 22 127.0.0.1:22" >> /etc/tor/torrc
RUN echo "HiddenServiceAuthorizeClient  stealth hidden_root" >> /etc/tor/torrc

RUN usermod -s /bin/bash root
RUN service ssh restart
RUN service tor restart

CMD ["/usr/sbin/sshd", "-D"]
```

Tor log:

```
Closed 1 streams for service [scrubbed].onion for reason resolve failed. Fetch status: No more HSDir available to query
```

Error from torify:

```
1690991052 ERROR torsocks[7188]: Host unreachable (in socks5_recv_connect_reply() at socks5.c:539)
ssh: connect to host b6aytqwa2yohkehkokd6cj6i47dfd5dlra3p42nhw7jx7kawdfpjkyad.onion port 22: No route to host
```

Comment: A Docker container only runs a single process, and an image doesn't persist running processes at all.  `RUN service ... restart` doesn't do anything.  Your container is only running the ssh daemon.  Can you split this into two separate containers?

Comment: Then how this provide me tor address ?